# Read Only Columns & Rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in a WinForms application and I want all columns bar one to be locked to editing.  This I was able to achieve with the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in myGrid.Columns)
{
    if (col.Name == "LockedColumn")
    {
        col.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        col.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

However, I also need a conditional lock on this column, dependent on the values elsewhere in each row.  I tried the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
{
    if ((bool)row.Cells["ConditionalColumn"].Value == false)
    {
        row.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        row.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

However this locks the whole grid which is not what I want.  What I'm after may be clearer with a table example.

ColA    ColB    ColC

row1    true    value1

row2    false   value2

row3    true    value3

I want Columns A & B locked (read only) in their entirety, and the default for Col C to allow editing, except where the value in Column B is false.  Hence in the above example only value1 and value3 would be editable.

However I can't seem to achieve this, because as stated above, if I loop through the rows with a condition that sets readonly to false, everything is locked.

Comment: Is this the actual code from your project? You cannot cast a datagridview cell to bool so this code should not compile. Also it isn't very clear what your problem is. Are you saying that when you set a row readonly the whole grid becomes readonly? This does not  happen.

Comment: Why all the markdowns - what on earth is so wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote - surprised people have, but perhaps the non compiling code was the reason. Hopefully if you post the actual code from your project people will remove the downvotes.

Comment: Original post revised - I had missed out .Value which was in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the following line that was the issue

```
row.ReadOnly = false;
```

When changed to

```
row.Cells["colName"].ReadOnly = false;
```

it works as intended

Answer (score 3):

The code you have shown should not compile and also isn't correctly examining the values within boolean cells in a `DataGridView`.

If you change your code to look at rows to something like the code below then you should be able to set individual rows to read only based on the column:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["ConditionalColumn"].Value == null || (bool)row.Cells["ConditionalColumn"].Value == false)
    {
        row.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        row.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```